# Allow user to delete individual sessions on account, safe to embed sessions in HTML?

Tags: session-management, account-security

I am in the process of creating a web application that enables users to view all active sessions connected to their accounts and, if desired, delete them one by one individually.

[image]

One way I want to implement this is by sending links containing the actual `session_key` and embed them into the HTML like `https://www.example.com/session/delete/SESSION_KEY`.

Is this considered a good practice or is there a more efficient way to do this? Are there any risks that I am unaware of? Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: You will add a confirmation page, right?  (i.e. the user will need to confirm the intended deletion)

Comment: Is example.com suppose to be say Dropbox? Or is that your service? How will you ensure that the 3rd party itself invalidates the token?

Comment: Why not simply use the ID (Primary Key) and then validate permissions in the delete handler?

Comment: @thexacre, what do you mean? are you worried about csrf attacks?

Comment: @SilverlightFox the primary key is the session key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would this be considered good practice or is there a better way to do this?

No, this doesn't seem to be ideal.

The biggest problem I see is that you put a session id into the HTML of a page. It is best practice to make session cookies httpOnly to make XSS a bit harder to exploit. By putting the session id into the HTML, you leak that information in case of XSS, thus making httpOnly useless.

This may also be a problem if sensitive data is stored in a session, as someone who hijacked one session or account now has access to all sessions. The impact seems minor, but it doesn't seem ideal and may be a problem depending on the application.

Additionally, you don't have any CSRF protection which - while bad practice in general - doesn't have a security impact in this case as this isn't a very sensitive action and an attacker would need to know the session id, which they don't. Still, it doesn't seem ideal and also violates RESTful.

Finally, it's never a good idea to put sensitive data in a URL, it should instead be submitted via POST as it may otherwise leak in various ways. Again, this is likely not a security issue, as the data is useless as soon as it is used, but it doesn't follow best practices (and may be a problem, eg when the delete didn't work).

I would suggest to use ids that are independent of the actual session id, and to submit them via POST instead.

Comment: did you mean httpsONLY? (I apologize for a potentially trivial question)

Comment: @Alan no, `httpOnly` means that the cookie cannot be read out via javascript. This slightly mitigates XSS attacks (stealing cookies is an easy and quick way to exploit them). What you may be thinking of is the `secure` flag, which  prevents cookies from being send over http (so if you have ssl, you should set both).

Comment: I did not know of the httpOnly property, I always just assumed session cookies can be read like any other. 

Is there a special field or flag that marks a cookie as httpOnly?

Comment: @Alan yes, session cookies aren't really special, they can be read like any other. And yes, the flag is actually called `httpOnly` :) It looks like this in the HTTP header: `Set-Cookie: SID=[THE_SID]; secure; HttpOnly`. It depends on the language and framework you use if it is set automatically for session cookies (but it probably will be).

Answer (score 1):

If the session key is the session ID then **no it would not be a good practice**. The session ID is like gold. When you log in this ID is stored as a session cookie. If someone was to obtain this ID nothing would stop them from simply using the browser's dev tools to add the ID and they would be authenticated as that user without needing a username or password. The only place this should be exposed is as a browser session cookie since this is still a technical requirement for sessions.

Ideally these session IDs should have a unique reference key. And the key cannot recall a session but only be used to match the session ID in the session store to delete it. This key you could expose with little risk compared to the ID. This way the worst that comes of it is getting the session deleted.

Comment: What is your personal preference for this unique reference key then? `UUID` or `hash(session_key)`?

Comment: I would not hash what you could generate completely unique.